# The way of handling In-App browsers authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I think the title is self describing.

Most of nowadays Apps like Twitter, Discord, Reddit, Instagram, Messenger - they open web links inside their own in-app browsers.
This causes some issues on web apps end.
One of it is broken Authentication, for example from Firebase - The problem known as `disallowed user agent` <- Google blocks their auth inside insecure browsers (like in-app browsers).

The work around is sometimes to detect the user agent and based on that, perform some logic:

```
export const isInAppBrowser = () => {
    const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

    if (userAgent.includes('FBAN') || userAgent.includes('FBAV')) {
        return true; // Facebook app
    }
    if (userAgent.includes('Twitter')) {
        return true; // Twitter app
    }
    if (userAgent.includes('GSA/')) {
        return true; // Google Search App
    }
    if (userAgent.includes('Instagram')) {
        return true; // Instagram app
    }
    if (userAgent.includes('Pinterest')) {
        return true; // Pinterest app
    }

    return false;
};
```

Then we have some options like:

1. trying to open the web app inside native/default mobile browser (Safari, Chrome), using window.open:

```
   const inAppBrowser = isInAppBrowser();

   if (inAppBrowser) {
       const newWindow = window.open(window.location.href);
   }
```

2. The above will probably almost fail, so we can only end up politely asking user to open the link in their mobile browser:

```
// Considering above code + some UI (React example)
if (!newWindow || newWindow.closed || typeof newWindow.closed === 'undefined')
return (
<div>
  <p>This browser does not support all the functionalities.</p>
  <p>Please open this page in your default browser.</p>
  <button>copy this link</button>
</div>
)
```

The overall problem is a huge conversion killer for startups, small businesses that don't have a native app, but rely on providing the best possible experience in mobile browser.

Also, relying on user agent is not a bullet proof solution. Then, even if we correctly check the user-agent, the first solution will probably fail;
The second depends on the user's patience and still may be a conversion killer. Or to say it simply - it's not the best experience we may provide to our users.

I wonder how you solve this problem, and what are yours workaround for that? Do you maybe use some tricks I don't know yet, do you implement authentication yourself in such scenarios and you resign from authentication based on other providers?

I'm just actively studying and researching this topic to provide better experience for users. We live in PWA era, where we try close the gap between native and web and we have strong technology for these scenarios - but we can get stuck on the in-app browsers behavior and consequences of that, which I described above.